# Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Token has been revoked.", Uri:""

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I have an MVC app, like explained here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

From Javascript I make AJAX calls to some Action that uses Google API to get message from Gmail.

At first everything works fine, but after some time I keep receiving

> Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Token has been revoked.", Uri:""

Can someone explain to me what that means and why I am getting this error ???

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

> Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Token has been revoked.", Uri:""

Means just that the user has revoked your access to their data you will need to request authentication again.

One thing you need to remember is that while testing.  If you request access from yourself you grant it get a refresh token, do it again you get another refresh token.  They both will work.   You can do this up to 26 times and have 26 technically live and active refresh tokens for an application.  Once you do it the 27th time the first one will stop working normally you just get an invalid grant error.

Token has been revoked normally means that the user has revoked access in Google but it might be different with Gmail.

## Update 2021:

Invalid grant means that the token you have no longer works.  As of 2021 google has made a change which will cause all refresh tokens to expire after seven days if the project that created it is still in the testing phase. The solution is to move your project to production and then your refresh tokens will last longer then seven days.

Comment: What user? I am the only one who is using my app, and I didnt revoke anything.

Comment: Are you saying a new refreshtoken everytime you test your authentication?

Comment: If you are doing this with JavaScript remember that access token is only good for an hour and you will need to request authorization again

Comment: Yes, I know access token is for 1 hour only. I am not using javascript, I am using Google API Client Library for .NET. I am assigning previously saved refresh token to RefreshToken property of Credentials.Token object, that contains AccessTocken and RefreshToken. This way if  AccessToken expired, when I make a call to Google API, it should acquire a new AccessToken automatically.

Comment: Where are you saving this refreshtoken?

Comment: In web.config only the first time upon initial authorization. Then, I am assigning it to RefreshToken property before making calls to Google API. As far as I understand I dont need to check if it expired or acquire a new access token myself manually, Google API does that for me automatically, when it has a refresh token

Comment: @DalmTo: I have seen in your profile you worked on Google API library, am I correct with my assumption that when I make a call, lets say to Gmail Service: var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = credential }); that credential.Token.AccessToken will get a new value upon its expiration, if credential.Token.RefreshToken was set to the value I saved previously on initial authorization (after a user clicks Allow on consent screen)?

Comment: If you are testing authentication requesting access of yourself again.  You get a new refresh token you can have 26 of these live once you have done it the 27th time the first one expires. I suspect that is what you are hitting here.    But yes the client library will fetch you a new access token as long as it has a valid refresh token.